# ASP.NET MVC 5 & WebAPI 2 authentication

Tags: .net, authentication, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm making a web-service which will be accessible from web-interface and mobile apps. For web interface I use MVC 5 and WebAPI 2 for mobile apps. I need to setup two types of authentication:

1. Cookie-based for MVC part
2. Bearer token-based for WebAPI part

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this for #2

[Individual Accounts in ASP.NET Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/individual-accounts-in-web-api)